# Google Fit throws application needs OAuth consent from the user exception

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, permissions, google-fit-api

When trying to access user heart rate from my android application(kotlin) using google fit API I get the below error

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5000: Application
> needs OAuth consent from the user

I have added scope in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
```

I check for permission in my onCreate() function in MainActivity.kt file

Below is my code for that.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val email=intent.getStringExtra("email")
        val name=intent.getStringExtra("name")
      
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,BODY_SENSORS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            1+2;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(BODY_SENSORS),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
            // Permission is not granted
            }
}
```

Below is my code to retrieve heart rate data.

```
private fun accessGoogleFit() {
       
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val startTime = endTime - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1000)
  
        val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()

        val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, account)
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener({ response ->
                Log.i(response.toString(), "OnSuccess()")
            })
            .addOnFailureListener({ e -> Log.d(TAG, "OnFailure()", e) })
    }
```

I have followed all the instructions given in this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key)

Any idea on how to fix this? Do I have to add more configurations on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)  or in my kotlin application